# what is the syntax for updating a numberlong field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I ran the following command and it did not update the records needed:

```
db.email_queue.update({agent_id:"55d4ec8578d34f8e048b4e56"},{$set:{cancelled:1}},{multi:true})
```

The mongo records look like this:

```
"canceled": NumberLong(0)
```

need it to look like this:

```
"canceled": NumberLong(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you have "canceled" in your record, and you try to update the field "cancelled".

Comment: good catch.  still not updating properly.  now just says "canceled:1"

Answer (score 0):

here's how I did it:

```
db.email_queue.update({agent_id:"55d4ec8578d34f8e048b4e56"},{$set:{canceled:NumberLong("1")}},{multi:true})
```

hope that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. Below are few tests which i ran in my mongo terminal.

```
Insert type 1
db.test.insert( { _id:10, calc: NumberLong("209") } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : NumberLong("209") }

Insert type 2
db.test.insert( { _id:10, calc: NumberLong(209) } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : NumberLong(209) }

Update type 1
db.test.update( { _id: 10 },{ $set:  { calc: 007 } } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : 007 }

Update type 2
db.test.update( { _id: 10 },{ $set:  { calc: "007" } } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : "007" }

Update type 3
db.test.update( { _id: 10 },  { $set:  { calc: NumberLong("007") } } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : NumberLong(007) }

Update type 4
db.test.update( { _id: 10 },  { $set:  { calc: NumberLong(007) } } );
// Result - { "_id" : 10, "calc" : NumberLong(007) }
```